# Get a space (height and width of a div)

Tags: scrapy

For my scrapy results there are different divs, where I read my data from.
Some of those divs are taking more space, like "Offer of a day", and I want for my project extract a space, every div is taking (height * width).

The problem is, I am scraping multiple hosts and I need the solution to be kept dynamic, so I do not want to check specific css classes for each host (as those can change with the time and I would not be able to review it oftenly).

The divs are defined not with the style property, but using classes.

So I could only extract the names of the classes inside of divs, but not the css properties of the class.
Could I somehow using scrapy read what are the definitions of each class on the webpage?

For example, class ".dayOffer" = { width: 30%, height: 20rem }?

Comment: No...  Not unless the css is defined in the html page, and even then scrapy doesn't provide any means of doing this, you would have to find the `style` tags and parse the contents yourself.